# aws python cdk: how to solve constructs version conflict (trying to create httpapi)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

Goal (quite simple, or at least I thought so):

- Returning HTML-Content from a lambda for a web browser.
- Defining it with python aws cdk

As far as I understand it, I've got to put my lambda into an `HttpLambdaIntegration` which I can use in a route added to my `HttpApi`

Here is the example:

```
from aws_cdk.aws_apigatewayv2_integrations import HttpLambdaIntegration

# books_default_fn: lambda.Function

books_integration = HttpLambdaIntegration("BooksIntegration", books_default_fn)

http_api = apigwv2.HttpApi(self, "HttpApi")

http_api.add_routes(
    path="/books",
    methods=[apigwv2.HttpMethod.GET],
    integration=books_integration
)
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/python/aws_cdk.aws_apigatewayv2_integrations/README.html

So far I found:

`HttpLambdaIntegration` here: https://pypi.org/project/aws-cdk.aws-apigatewayv2-integrations/

`HttpApi` here: https://pypi.org/project/aws-cdk.aws-apigatewayv2-alpha/#defining-http-apis

But I can`t install both because of a version clash:

> The conflict is caused by:
>
> aws-cdk-lib 2.56.1 depends on constructs<11.0.0 and >=10.0.0
>
> aws-cdk-aws-apigatewayv2-alpha 2.56.1a0 depends on constructs<11.0.0
> and >=10.0.0
>
> aws-cdk-aws-apigatewayv2-integrations 1.184.1 depends on
> constructs<4.0.0 and >=3.3.69

Am I using the wrong packages? Or am I on the wrong track anyway? The version mash up is quite confusing in the whole...

**UPDATE (A few days later)**

Ok, good news: I got it running ... but I switched to Typescript, following this example: https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/aws-cdk-http-api-apigateway-v2-example

And I still had to install using npm with `--force`, which always makes me more or less unhappy, but at least I could and it works.

I've come now to the conclusion, that I can't really recommend the python aws cdk. This is at least the third time I tried, and at least the third time I ran into trouble ...  There are just a lot more typescript examples!